# Error opening opvn configuration file

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn

After downloading the **gns3vm.opvn** file provided by my remote server at Packet.net, as per instruction issued this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

... no problem ...
then this command:

```
$ sudo openvpn gns3vm.opvn 
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: gns3vm.opvn
```

I am a long time Mac user, and totally new to Ubuntu 18.04 .

Pls help thanks.

Comment: Where is the ovpn file located? You may add a path for the ovpn file like this: sudo openvpn /path/to/your/file/gns3vm.ovpn

Comment: @kukulo Thank you for the input.  I am using a Ubuntu 18.04 btw, the file was in the opvn folder in the bear-metal server, also Ubuntu 18.04.  I searched for it with the <find . -name "*file_name*"> command, that returned a long winding path to the file.  I pointed that in the <$ sudo openvpn {full path/gn3vm.ovpn}> code as you mentioned and it worked. Additionally -- not mentioned in GNS3 Packet VPN config guide -- I had to do the same on the client side after installing opvn, but the command required including {--config} before file path.  Then the vpn work.  Happiness!  Many thanks again.

Comment: I would be glad that you would accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the ovpn file located? You may add a path for the ovpn file like this:

```
sudo openvpn /path/to/your/file/gns3vm.ovpn
```

Eventually use `find . -name "file_name"` to get the path.